# strtotime() for MySQL date comparison with Joomla Development

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Working on a syntax issue, I'm trying to compare today's date to the event_start_date field in the database.  Here is my Joomla query:

```
public static function getEventsList() {

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $today = date("Y-m-d");

    $query
            ->select('*')
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__my_table'))
            ->where('event_start_date' . ' >= ' . $today);

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $results;
}
```

event_start_date table in the database is a Date column, and formatted like this:  2015-10-10

I think I need to convert $today to strtotime or DateTime so that I can properly compare today's date variable against the MySQL field.

There are a million posts about strtotime, but I can't get the right syntax.  Any advice?

Comment: `->where('event_start_date >= CURDATE()');` does this work ?

Comment: Yes!  Fixed, thank you!